# Meaning of HCF in a problem sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When a group of children shared a box of 200 beads equally , there were 4 beads left .
When the remaining heads were added to another box of 80 beads and shared equally , there were no beads left.
Calculate the number of beads left if 250 beads are shared equally among the children .

My try -

The first box got $200-4= 196$ beads

The second box got $80+4 = 84$ beads

$196 = 2^2 7^2 $, 
$ 84 = 2^2 3^17^1$

After this I found the HCF . But I'm not too sure why finding the HCF of these $2$ numbers can find the number of children in the group.

Comment: It doesn't. But the number of children must divide the highest common factor.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of children must divide $196$ and $84$ then it must be a common factor and so must divide their highest common factor $28$, so it must in $\{1,2,4,7,14,28\}$

But it cannot be in $\{1,2,4\}$ as these would have left a zero remainder on the first box of $200$. So number of children must be in $\{7,14,28\}$

These give different remainders when dividing into $250$, so the question does not have a single answer